# Объявление массивов

Tags: массивы, java

Доброго времени суток! не могу понять, чем отличаются объявления

```
String[] array
```

и

```
String array[]
```

? Отличаются ли чем-то эти массивы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, не отличаются. Но принято использовать запись `String[] array`, т.к. обозначение массива имеет все-таки большее отношение к типу переменной, чем к ее имени.

Comment: вопрос по java: а при  

    String[] array1,array2;

**array2 будет массивом?** если нет то *IMHO* правильнее писать String array[]

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat а чем по вашему еще может быть array2? Конечно это будет массив строк.

Comment: @a_gura просто я только начал изучать java (пока я 100% ноль)

потому и уточняю

Comment: @ProkletyPirat, у Вас ведь установлена Java?

Если да, то скажу Вам по секрету, что подобные вещи проще и значительно быстрее проверять парой команд:

    javac ...
    java ....

Вот если после этого что-то осталось неясно, то милости просим, спрашивайте.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat дело здесь не в Java, а в логике. Просто задумайтесь, если синтаксис `String[] array1,array2;` допустим, то что в этой записи может говорить о том, что переменная array2 имеет тип, отличный от String[]